# Change Progress Bar color if value is more that max value

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

How to change the colour of progress bar if the value is more than the max value set. which means the label on the progress bar can exceed the max value set to the progress bar and the color to be changed to red if the value is more than the max value.
if the value is more than the max value change to red else to blue.

```
code:
https://jsbin.com/hamehel/1/edit?html,output
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a flag that compares progress.max and progress.value?

```js
const progress = document.querySelector('#progress');
const up10 = () => {
  progress.value += 10;
  changeStyle();
};
const down10 = () => {
  progress.value -= 10;
  changeStyle();
};
const changeStyle = () => {
  if (progress.max > progress.value) {
    progress.classList.remove('progress-max')
  } else {
    progress.classList.add('progress-max')
  }
}
changeStyle();
```

```css
.progress-max {
  color: lightblue;
}
.progress-max::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: red;
}
.progress-max::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <progress id="progress" value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <button onclick="up10()">+ 10</button>
    <button onclick="down10()">-10</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ofcourse you can. The point is add the class if value is equal or higer then max and remove the class if valus is less then max.